# WPF Dragging listboxitems while zoomed in or out

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, listbox

I have a WPF project (C#, MVVM, Visual Studio 2010).

There is a ListBox in which there are items. The Items are freely moveable if the player uses click and drag to reposition them (the ItemsPanelTemplate is a Canvas control).

It works fine, but I also have a zoom in and out method which uses the mouse wheel.

The problem is that, in a zoomed in or zoomed out state, if one drags a ListBoxItem, it does not work quite right. Somehow the coordinates seem a little off.

Here is the mouse wheel method:

```
void OnPreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        lastMousePositionOnTarget = Mouse.GetPosition(NodeDragCanvas);

        if (e.Delta > 0)
        {
            if (dScaleValue < dZoomMax)
                dScaleValue += dZoomIncrementValue;
        }
        if (e.Delta < 0)
        {
            if(dScaleValue > dZoomMin)
                dScaleValue -= dZoomIncrementValue;
        }

        e.Handled = true;

        scaleTransform.ScaleX = dScaleValue;
        scaleTransform.ScaleY = dScaleValue;

        var centerOfViewport = new Point(NodeDragScrollViewer.ViewportWidth / 2, NodeDragScrollViewer.ViewportHeight / 2);
        lastCenterPositionOnTarget = NodeDragScrollViewer.TranslatePoint(centerOfViewport, NodeDragCanvas);
    }
```

Of course the mouse move method is also needed:

```
void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (lastDragPoint.HasValue)
        {
            Point posNow = e.GetPosition(NodeDragScrollViewer);

            double dX = (posNow.X - lastDragPoint.Value.X);// *this.dScaleValue;
            double dY = (posNow.Y - lastDragPoint.Value.Y);// *this.dScaleValue;

            lastDragPoint = posNow;

            // This situation is a drag.
            if (LbNodes.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
            {
                NodeDragScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(NodeDragScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset - dX);
                NodeDragScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(NodeDragScrollViewer.VerticalOffset - dY);
            }
            else
            {
                // This situation is mouse drag of items
                foreach (ChatNodeViewModel cv in LbNodes.SelectedItems)
                {
                    cv.XCoord += dX;
                    cv.YCoord += dY;
                }

                // This bit just causes the lines between the nodes to update.
                Mediator.EventMediator.Instance.RefreshAllNodesDraggable();
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can perhaps see, I tried to fumble it a little above by multiplying the dX and dY by the scale value. It didn't seem to work.

To explain perhaps a little more. Okay, let's say we have a ListBoxItem that is just an image. In a normal (default) zoom level, you can click this item and move it around. While moving it around, the mouse cursor stays in the same place relative to the ListBoxItem. In a zoomed state, it drifts around, and might even leave the ListBoxItem. Obviously there's some relationship between where it should be and where it is based on the zoom level, but I don't know what it is.

I don't know if there is a standard solution here, but certainly I would appreciate some guidance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, good internet etiquette is to reply if I found a solution (which I did).

I played around with a few ideas... but the main one I seemed to not realise is that applying any changes to dX and dY would also apply to the zoom (since it's used for both that AND the mouse dragging).

So I created two separate variables (dMouseDragX and dMouseDragY) to experiment on. The first thing I tried, since I realised the drift was greater if I zoomed in and less if I zoomed out, was to create an alternative to the dScaleValue variable, which increased when dScale value decreased, and increased when dScaleValue decreased. This got me closer, but not close enough to call success. Still, I was on the right track - it was some inverse of dScaleValue that I needed. And then... well... I used the inverse. And it worked.

So the MouseMove now looks like this:

```
void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (lastDragPoint.HasValue)
        {
            Point posNow = e.GetPosition(NodeDragScrollViewer);

            double dX = (posNow.X - lastDragPoint.Value.X);
            double dY = (posNow.Y - lastDragPoint.Value.Y);

            // This was a bit of a guess, but it seems to work like a charm.
            double dMouseDragX = (posNow.X - lastDragPoint.Value.X) * (1/dScaleValue);
            double dMouseDragY = (posNow.Y - lastDragPoint.Value.Y) * (1/dScaleValue);


            lastDragPoint = posNow;

            // This situation is a drag.
            if (LbNodes.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
            {
                NodeDragScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(NodeDragScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset - dX);
                NodeDragScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(NodeDragScrollViewer.VerticalOffset - dY);
            }
            else
            {
                // This situation is mouse drag of items
                foreach (ChatNodeViewModel cv in LbNodes.SelectedItems)
                {
                    cv.XCoord += dMouseDragX;
                    cv.YCoord += dMouseDragY;
                }

                // This bit just causes the lines between the nodes to update.
                Mediator.EventMediator.Instance.RefreshAllNodesDraggable();
            }
        }
    }
```

So it's almost the same, but with the inverse being applied to the mouse drag... and that's it!